# how to write Recursive CTE in SQL server 2012 for hour and min

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I would like to generate a list of half an hour interval. Any suggestion would be very helpful. I tried this and did not work. Thank you

```
WITH cte
AS (select convert(varchar, DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate())), 108)  AS Today

    UNION ALL

    SELECT dateadd(MINUTE, 30, Today) AS Today
    FROM cte
    WHERE dateadd(MINUTE, 30,Today) < (select convert(varchar, DATEADD(Day, 1, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate())), 108))
    )
SELECT*
FROM cte
```

To get:

```
0:00 
0:30
1:00
1:30
2:00
2:30
3:00
3:30
4:00
4:30
5:00
5:30
6:00
6:30
7:00
7:30
8:00
8:30
9:00
9:30
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00
12:30
13:00
13:30
14:00
14:30
15:00
15:30
16:00
16:30
17:00
17:30
18:00
18:30
19:00
19:30
20:00
20:30
21:00
21:30
22:00
22:30
23:00
23:30
0:00
```

Comment: Thank you bluefeet for edit. I am still learning to write correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert the time to a `VARCHAR` and then use `DATETIME` functions on it, you need to keep it as a `DATETIME` throughout the recursive portion:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, dt) AS dt
              FROM cte
              WHERE dt < DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE())
              )
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),dt, 108)
FROM  cte
```